# iOS Swift - Export Data from Custom Table View Cells on Exit/Save

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 5 custom UITableViewCells. In the custom UITableViewCells I have IBOutlets for my UI-elements (UILabel, UITextField). I cannot create IBOutlets for the UI-elements in my view controller because they are already linked to my custom UITableViewCells.

I want to be able to access the data in my UITableViewCells when the UIBarButtonItem of type "Save" is pressed. In order to parse the data from my UITableViewCells to my own class.

I have already written the unwind method in the return controller, and have written the prepareForSegue method in the source controller, got that working. I only need to retrieve the data from the custom UITableViewCells at that specific time (on save, not on finished editing textfield or when a table row has been dis-selected).

What would be the "best practice" to achieve this kind of behaviour?

Comment: you are using only one Table View Cell Class?  I mean table is dynamic?

Comment: I use 5 prototype cells. See linked image.

https://s13.postimg.io/td56d0d1x/Screen_Shot_2016_09_05_at_2_57_04_PM.png

Comment: will it be possible for you to use static table instead of dynamic?

Comment: I want to use dynamic.

Comment: You should not count on the table view cells being "alive" for the duration of the view controller. Cells are recycled, and this happens a lot quicker than you might imagine. You need to save the data back to your table view controller as soon as possible. The table view controller can then save this data to permanent storage when you actually tap Save.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know what your custom cells look like, I'll just use a cell that has a single text field in it (named `myTextField`) as an example.

In the custom cell class, add a property like this:

```
var value: String? {
    return myTextField.text
}
```

And in the save button's `@IBAction` method, do this:

```
var data = [String]()
let sections = numberOfSectionsInTableView(self.tableView)
for s in 0..<sections {
    let rows = tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: s) 
    for r in 0..<rows {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: r, inSection: s)) as! YourCustomCell
        data.append(cell.value)
    }
}
```

And now you have an array of strings!

If your cell's data is not as simple as a string, please consider using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka).